# Automator Keeps Opening Multiple Untitled Files

Tags: automator

Exactly what the title says. Whenever I open Automator, by clicking on its icon, it keeps opening multiple files (Untitled, Untitled 2, Untitled 3). When I attempt to close them it asks me if I want to save changes for each one. This is incredibly annoying. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: I've flagged this as a dupe because I discovered a much better way since I wrote the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I discovered a much better way since I wrote this* - see [Choose which Applications re-open documents at launch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459821/choose-which-applications-re-open-documents-at-launch)

Delete the Saved State files.

- Quit Automator.
- Bring Finder to the front.
- Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Window, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go To...
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Automator.savedState`
- Delete the folder contents.