# In Terminal how do I re-enable trackpad swiping on chrome?

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome, trackpad

I used the following terminal text to disable trackpad back swiping on chrome:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE
```

How do I undo this command to regain use of the swiping feature? I did this because it kept messing with a project I was working on in google sheets and now I've made a grave mistake.

Comment: Do the same thing but change `FALSE` to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse a boolean [on/off] `defaults write` you have two options, depending on whether there was ever a default in the first place - you may need to test this.

If there was always a default in the prefs, then you reverse it by reversing the boolean value, e.g.

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool TRUE
```

Some applications prefer `0` or `1` but if `FALSE` already worked, then `TRUE` should also.

Alternatively, if there was no default initially, you can remove it using

```
defaults delete com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls
```

This is more important with any default which also has a global function. Reversing the default will make it always override the global. Deleting it will make it revert to whatever the global is set to.

See [Choose which Applications re-open documents at launch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459821/choose-which-applications-re-open-documents-at-launch) for an example of when you may need to differentiate these behaviours.

You will usually have to re-launch the app to see the change.